# React Native Debugger Not Working on iOS simulator or actual iPhone

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I used `npm init -g <project>`. The app uses a blank template.

I started the app using `npm start`.

I open the debugger in the iOS simulator by hitting `j`. However, the app instantly loses connection. This same thing happens when I use expo go on my actual iPhone. Does anyone know what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: For some reason it works fine when I use `expo-cli start --tunnel` but not `npm start --tunnel`